# Need explanation of Word2 variable

Tags: c, cstring, strcpy

I DO UNDERSTAND THAT THIS PROGRAM IS NOT ALLOCATING ENOUGH MEMORY.

What I need help with is describing an explanation of what happens when this code is executed.

I put "Since only 4 spaces are allocated it is not given enough space so it causes an error." Which doesn't sound right to me. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char word1[20];
    char *word2;

    word2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

    printf("Sizeof word 1: %d\n", sizeof (word1));  //This line outputs 20
    printf("Sizeof word 2: %d\n", sizeof (word2));  //This line outputs 4
                                                    //before & after I used malloc
    strcpy(word1, "string number 1");
    strcpy(word2, "string number 2"); <---- What is this doing

    printf("%s\n", word1);
    printf("%s\n", word2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeof( word2 )  returns 4 because that is the size of the pointer

```
char *word2;
```

is a pointer and there is 0 Bytes allocated for it ( not 4 as you mentioned)

sizeof( word1 ) returns 20 becuase that is the size of array

```
char word1[20]
```

is an array and there is 20 Bytes reserved for it

Comment: Ok one more question... does the code allocate memory exactly the same for word1/word2? Added in dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4):

word2 is an uninitialised pointer.  Writing data to it has undefined consequences but will probably crash.  You need to allocate memory for it on the stack (as for `word1`) or  dynamically, using `malloc`.

```
char *word2 = malloc(20); // arbitrary value. could use strlen(some_str)+1 also
strcpy(word2, "string number 2"); // works now
```

or, for posix systems

```
char *word2 = strdup("string number 2");
```

In either case, make sure to later call `free` to return this memory to the system.

Note that even after allocating memory, `sizeof(word2)` will remain 4.  This is because `word2` has type `char*` so `sizeof` is reporting the size of `char*` rather than the memory it points to.

Comment: Ok one more question... does the code allocate memory exactly the same for word1/word2? Added in dynamic allocation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. In your current code, both `word1` and `word2` are allocated on the stack and will be automatically reclaimed when they go out of scope.  If you use `malloc` (or any intermediate function which uses it), the memory allocated will remain allocated until you call `free`.  If this doesn't answer your question, can you try re-stating it please?

Comment: Basically when I allocate word1 to size 20, is it the same as dynamically allocating *word2 to 20?

Comment: the first 3 lines of the int main function basically.

Comment: Either approach gives you a 20 byte buffer.  `word1` is a stack based buffer so its memory is returned to the system (so unsafe for you to use) when `word1` goes out of scope.  If `word2` is dynamically allocated, you control how long its memory is available for (by deciding when to call `free`)

Answer (score 0):

In your program `word2` will have some previous value or probably a junk value. When you perform `strcpy(word2, "string number 2");`, you are trying to write to a location to which you don't have access to and hence, your program crashes. So, you need to allocate sufficient memory into which your program can write into.